# TortoiseSVN equivalent commands for TortoiseGit

Tags: git, tortoisesvn, tortoisegit

I am familiar with TortoiseSVN, but not with TortoiseGit 
So am looking at basic equivalents for TortoiseGit.

Like for the common things we do;

```
SVN > Update
SVN > Commit
SVN > Add
```

What are the similar GUI equivalents for TortoiseGit ?

Comment: Perhaps you should learn git first and then go for the GUI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GIT SCM is different from SVN

In SVN you have the options of **Add, Commit, Update**. 
**Add** in SVN is only used to add new files to the repository, when preparing for a commit. **Commit** in SVN will allow you to update the remote repository with your changes.
**Update** will let you know if there are changes in the remote and update your working copy.

In GIT you will have **Add to Index, Commit, Push to Upstream, Fetch from Upstream, Pull**. **Add** in GIT is used to submit any change to any file (including new files) to the Git index, in preparation for a subsequent commit. **Commit** in GIT doesn't update the remote repository, you will need to **Push** your changes to the remote in order to update. **Fetch** will let you know if you have any changes in the remote and **Pull** will actually update your working copy with the changes in the remote.

Comment: Awesome reply...Exactly what i was looking for